# "Minimum" regularity required for differentiating under the integral sign?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\rho(x)$ be defined on $\Omega$. Then, for each $z \in \Omega$, define the following integral

$$F(z) = \int_{\Omega} \rho(x)\|x-z\|^2 \,dx,  $$ where the norm $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Then, what would be a weakest condition to requireon $\rho(x)$ to guarantee that the function $F(z)$ is $C^1(\Omega)$?

If $\rho$ is $L^1(\Omega)$, then would this guarantee $C^1$ smoothnes of $F$?

Answer (score 0):

We certainly need $\rho \in L^1(\Omega)$ in order for the function to exist at all (assuming you're using Lebesgue integration).
Then $$ F(z) = \int_\Omega \rho(x) (\|x\|^2 - 2 x \cdot z + \|z\|^2)\; dx 
= A - 2 z \cdot B + \|z\|^2 C$$

where $$ \eqalign{A &= \int_\Omega \rho(x) \|x\|^2\; dx\cr
                  B &= \int_\Omega \rho(x) x\; dx\cr
                  C &= \int_\Omega \rho(x)\; dx\cr}$$
all exist since $\rho \in L^1$ and the region is bounded.  In particular, $F$ is smooth.